# Drawing torus in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I need to draw a torus which is very thin. What I found by searching internet is just formal description of the function `glutSolidTorus()` But problem is probably I am not getting what they are saying about the parameter. Every time I am trying to draw it by changing the parameters what comes out is a very fat torus.

```
glutSolidTorus(1.0f, 0.005f, 32, 32);
```

What I thought is that 1 unit is total torus radius and cross section(fat or thin determining) radius is 0.005 unit. Certainly I am wrong. Can somebody please explain me what's the problem and what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node84.html 
I noticed the following:

```
void glutSolidTorus(GLdouble innerRadius,
                    GLdouble outerRadius,
                    GLint nsides, GLint rings);
```

And your shape for the torus is that the inner radius is bigger that the outer radius. Try switching them around and see if that is what you want.

```
lutSolidTorus(0.005f, 1.00f, 32, 32);
```

The thickness of the torus is defined by the first parameter, innerRadius, while the second one defines how wide the torus spreads.

Edit:
please visit the link in the comment bellow.

Comment: The schematics on http://kikillers.tistory.com/142 show where each parameter gets applied for all solids (and, indeed, you got to have the *order* right!).

Comment: I read it wrong. I read first one is outer and second one is outer.